# Actualizar proyecto en Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, control-de-versiones

Voy al grano, ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de actualizar un proyecto de angular que está en una versión muy antigua a la última versión?

Por ejemplo:

Tengo un proyecto en Angular 7 y quiero pasarlo a la última versión actual que es Angular 12.

¿Debo pasar de 7 a 8 luego de 8 a 9, 9 a 10, etc?
ó
¿Hago un ng update y ya?

Aunque, en vista de que la versión de nodejs condiciona la versión de angular que podemos instalar, creería que lo correcto es pasar de versión en versión hasta llegar a la última.

Gracias

Comment: Es correcto, la actualización debe hacerse en pasos. Primero actualizar a la versión siguiente, corregir los problemas generados por la actualización, probar que la aplicación sigue funcionando correctamente y luego actualizar a la siguiente versión. https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

```
Fuente update.angular.io  no soporta migrar saltando versiones

Antes del Update verificar si usas  HttpClientModule y HttpClient service.

Durante el Update
```

> 1.`npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8`
>
> 2.`(deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep`
>
> 3.verificar estar usando versión >v14.15.0de Node
> 4.  using dynamic .imports...>loadChildren is deprecated -->verificar que se usa nueva
> sintaxis   `loadChildren: () => import(:..)`
>
> 5.`npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`
>
> 6. `npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9`
>
> 7.`ng add @angular/localize`
>
> 8. `npx @angular/cli@10 update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10`
> 9. ng update
>
> 10.`npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11`
>
> 11. ng update
> 12. `npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`
>
> 13.ng update

Answer (score 0):

Angular tiene una herramienta para ayudarte con la migración entre sus versiones. https://update.angular.io/

Si seleccionas dos versiones diferentes entre si con más de una versión mayor de diferencia te devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

> Warning: Be sure to follow the guide below to migrate your application to the new version. You can't run ng update to update Angular applications more than one major version at a time.

> Precausión. Asegurate de seguir la guía siguiente para migrar tu aplicación a la nueva versión. No puedes correr `ng update` para acutalizar aplicaciones Angular más de una versión mayor a la vez.

Despues de eso te lista una seríe de pasos a seguir.

Hay que tomar en cuenta que entre versiones habrá que ir cambiando la versión de nodejs.

Puedes ver un ejemplo aquí:

https://update.angular.io/?v=7.0-16.0

Answer (score -1):

Esto me ha servido a mi para pasar de una versión 7 a la actual:

1. Actualizar npm

   $ npm install -g npm@latest
2. Actualizar node

   $ nvm install v14.17.6  (o la versión más actual)
3. Actualizar angular

   $ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   $ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
4. Ir a la carpeta de tu proyecto y teclear

   $ npm install

En mi caso ha servido.